# Why does NumPy return "no fill-function for data-type" when an array is created with dtype=bool?

Tags: numpy

The `np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i == j, (3, 3), dtype=int)` call works perfectly and results in an array for which `.dtype` returns `dtype('bool')`.

However, if I explicitly specify `dtype=bool` in the function call, I get the following error:

> ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

It needs to construct the coordinates for the `(3,3)` array, this cant be done when the array is of `dtype=bool`.

Under the hood it calls `np.arange(...,dtype=bool)`, which cant be done, resulting in this exact error.

Answer (score 1):

`fromfunction` just does:

```
args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
return function(*args, **kwargs)
```

`dtype` is passed to `indices`.  It has nothing to do with the result returned by your `function`.

`np.indices` does

```
for i, dim in enumerate(dimensions):
    idx = arange(dim, dtype=dtype).reshape(
        shape[:i] + (dim,) + shape[i+1:]
    )

In [354]: np.indices((3,3))
Out[354]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
In [355]: np.indices((3,3),dtype=bool)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-355-75b7ff9469d4>", line 1, in <module>
    np.indices((3,3),dtype=bool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1772, in indices
    idx = arange(dim, dtype=dtype).reshape(
ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.
```

See the error in `arange`?

Making a matrix like [354] doesn't make sense for `bool`, does it?

Look again at the `fromfunction` docs:

```
dtype : data-type, optional
    Data-type of the coordinate arrays passed to `function`.
    By default, `dtype` is float.
```

`dtype` is for the coordinates passed to `function`, not the result of `function`.

### edit

At the risk of being redundant, here's the **full** traceback when using your code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-358-dfc87db48bcc>", line 1, in <module>
    np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i == j, (3, 3), dtype=bool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1845, in fromfunction
    args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1772, in indices
    idx = arange(dim, dtype=dtype).reshape(
ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.
```

Pay attention to each calling level - `fromfunction`, `indices`, `arange`.

### again

`fromfunction` gives the illusion of doing something significant, but as the initial quote shows, it just generates a `indices` and passes them to your function.

Your example could just as easily be done with a pair of broadcasted `arange`:

```
In [359]: np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i == j, (3, 3), dtype=int)
Out[359]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]])
In [360]: np.arange(3)[:,None]==np.arange(3)
Out[360]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]])
```